# Showing HashWithIndifferentAccess from acts_as_commentable_with_thread in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, hash, nested-sets

I am trying to display the contents of the nested comments and kind of stuck at something:

I am using acts_as_commentable_with_threads plugin (it uses awesome_nested_set).

In the controller, I have:

```
def show
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
   @all_comments = @team.comment_threads
   @root_comments = @team.root_comments
   @root_comment_content = @root_comments.first[:body] 
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end

def add_new_comment
   @team = Team.find(params[:id])
   @comment = Comment.build_from(@team, current_user.id, params[:comment])
   @comment.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
   @comment.save!
   redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @team
end
```

In the view, I have:

```
<b>Comments:</b>
<%  @root_comments.each do |comment| %>
<%= comment.body   %>
    <% end %>
```

The result is:

> Comments: --- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
>   body: asdvsdvasdfvasdvsdv ---
>   !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess body: sdvdsv ---
>   !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess title: TITITTLE
>   body: BODYDDBB

So the `@comment.body` is getting turned into a string.. How do I extract it the right way to get normal view?

Thanks in advance )

P.S. Would be absolutely amazing if somebody points me to an example of acts_as_commentable_with_threading - the description on git is not that clear and all the examples I found use acts_as_commentable

EDIT: This is the form that I am using..

```
 <%= form_tag "add_new_comment" do %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "id", @team.id %>
 <%= text_area_tag "comment[title]" %>Title
 <%= text_area_tag "comment[body]" %>Body
 <%= submit_tag "Post Comment" %>
 <% end %>
```

EDIT : I updated the controller and now it kinda works, but there has to be a more elegants way.. is there?

```
@team = Team.find(params[:id])
@comment = Comment.build_from(@team, current_user.id, params[:comment])
@comment.body = params[:comment][:body]
@comment.title = params[:comment][:title]
@comment.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
@comment.save!
```

Answer (score 2):

I watch the acts_as_commentable_with_threads plugin source. I see

```
def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment)
  c = self.new
  c.commentable_id = obj.id 
  c.commentable_type = obj.class.name 
  c.body = comment 
  c.user_id = user_id
  c
end
```

so your params[:comment] should be a string, but the result seems you give params[:comment] as a hash. that's why your view show ruby object string.

Comment: thanks, getting closer - I added the form that I am using for posting comments.. can you suggest something based on that?